# How to test if type is specialization of template with non-type parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

I was wondering if there was any solution to find if a type was a specialization of a template that takes non-type parameters without specifying every type ?

For instance, if have a class like this:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t R>
struct F {}
```

For now, I'm using a very specialized traits:

```
template<template<typename, std::size_t> class TT, typename T>
struct is_2 : std::false_type { };

template<template<typename, std::size_t> class TT, typename V1, std::size_t R>
struct is_2<TT, TT<V1, R>> : std::true_type { };
```

and used like `is_2<F, T>::value`. However, this is not practical since, if you add another template parameter, you have to edit your traits. Moreover, if you have several templates of this kind, you need to write a traits for each of them.

Is there any way to make something more practical ? I can use C++14. And I don't mean using a macro to reduce the code amount.

Comment: Did you try anything with variadic templates ?

Comment: Yes, but if you use typename..., it will only match types not bool or std::size_t. I'd need a Any... for that to work.

Comment: You can emulate `Any...` with `std::integral_constant` for non-type template parameters.

Comment: Are you free to modify (i.e., add something) to `F`?

Comment: @DanielFrey In that case, yes, I'm totally free to modify it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Non-type template parameters are a bit of a red headed stepchild.

There is no "any template parameter is matched, type or not".

If you can modify `F`, you make it more uniform by wrapping your constants in thin types.  So:

```
template<typename T, class R>
struct F;

template<typename T, std::size_t R>
struct F<T, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, R>> {};
```

now meta-programs like `is` can be written uniformly:

```
template<template<class...>class Template, class T>
struct is_instantiation : std::false_type {};
template<template<class...>class Template, class... Ts>
struct is_instantiation<Template, Template<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};
```

matching everything.

If you have less control over `F`, you can either use your approach, or write metaprogram that hoists both a `template` and an instance of that `template` into something with type wrappers.

```
struct meta_F {
  template<class T, std::size_t R>using raw_apply=F<T,R>;
  template<class T, class R>using apply=raw_apply<T,R::value_type>;
};

template<class meta_Template, class... Args>
struct type_lifted_template {};

template<class T, std::size_t R>
struct type_lifted_template< meta_F, T, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, R> > {
  using result = meta_F::template raw_apply<T, R>;
};

template<class T, std::size_t R>
auto type_lift_instance( F<T,R> )
-> type_lifted_template< meta_F, T, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, R> >;
```

Now, `type_lift_instance` can be specialized for multiple types, and some `decltype` magic could be used to extract the `type_lifted_template` specialization for different types.

All of this is pretty rough.  You'd be best, if you are doing lots of meta programming on templates, to just have your templates take uniform type parameters, instead of messing around with this stuff.

```
template<class meta_F, class C>
struct meta_template_is_lifted : std::false_type {};
template<class meta_F, class...Ts>
struct meta_template_is_lifted<meta_F, type_lifted_template< meta_F, Ts... >> : std::true_type {};

template<class meta_F, class C>
struct meta_template_is : meta_template_is_lifted< meta_F, decltype(type_lift_instance( std::declval<C>() ) ) > {};
```

this isn't much less typing, but the metafication goes on far away from the `is` code (or other similar code).

I'm probably using "lift" incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

If you can modify `F` and there are no other restrictions you haven't mentioned, the easiest solution would be to add a unique base class:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

struct unique_F_base {};

template<typename T, std::size_t R>
struct F : unique_F_base
{
};

template<typename T>
using is_F = std::is_base_of<unique_F_base,T>;

int main()
{
    static_assert( !is_F< int >::value, "Oops" );
    static_assert( is_F< F<int,42> >::value, "Oops" );
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, I haven't thought of that. The problem with that is that, if I have several classes like F (but with other non-type parameters, I'll have to add a base class to each of them.

Comment: @BaptisteWicht It's one line per base class, you need to compare the overhead and the complexity of that against other solutions. Adding a base class is not sexy, but it's easy, straight-forward and the axe-murderer maintaining your code in 2 years will have no problem with it :)